# .innerHTML from .js file?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

i want to print all text from .js file  to div

```
document.getElementById('cart-status').innerHTML = "/numberOfcart.js"
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase this question?  It sounds like you want to display the source of the JavaScript--the code itself--as though it were HTML content.  Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to do something like this:

```
$.get('/numberOfcart.js', function(data) {
  $('#cart-status').text(data);
}
```

but you are simply loading in the .js file, not running it.

Answer (score 0):

Directly displaying the the contents of js file by JavaScript is not possible (or I don`t know, if somebody knows a way - welcome). So by PHP:

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'script.js' );
echo "<pre>" . htmlentities ( $file ) . "</pre>";
```

With an ajax callback to the php script, set to the div.

Comment: Actually, you can test the jQuery answer and see that as long as it's on the same server, there's not a problem loading a javascript file (or any other file) into a div.

Comment: I think it is about showing the source of the js. But for loading, you are wright.